# Why is an error thrown from line 28 in this code at https://jsfiddle.net/t19va6ff/ , but line 32 works?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

interested in knowing why line 28 throws an error "undefined", but enclosing the functions within an IIFE seems to resolve the problem

what if the code was modified to this instead:

var tabs = ['Search', 'Era'];

```
function verifySearchTab(){
    console.log("verify search tab");
}

function verifyEraTab(){
  console.log("verify era tab");
}

tabs.forEach(tab => {
    console.log(typeof `verify${tab}Tab`);
  `verify${tab}Tab`();
});
```

Comment: posting your code would help

Comment: **WHEN YOU COMPLETELY REFACTOR YOUR CODE DAYS AFTER THE ORIGINAL QUESTION WAS ASKED, ASK A NEW QUESTION**

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**
Like you mentioned in a comment below when you just declare a function in a script it is a member of `window` so you would address it the same as if it was a member of an "object" or "function" `funcs`

```js
var tabs = ['Search', 'Era'];

function verifySearchTab(){
    console.log("verify search tab");
}

function verifyEraTab(){
  console.log("verify era tab");
}

tabs.forEach(tab => {
  console.log(typeof window[`verify${tab}Tab`]);
  window[`verify${tab}Tab`]();
});
```

to further explain why how this works in javascript the `` ` `` character with help do a string function so when you do the following:

```
console.log(typeof `verify${tab}Tab`);
```

the output will be

> string

in javascript a string is an object and not a function, however in javascript you can access a member of an object by its string name. so the following code

```
console.log(typeof window[`verify${tab}Tab`]);
```

gives

> function

so that is how you access the function not just a string this may make more sense looking at these two lines of code that accomplish the same thing

```
`verify${tab}Tab`();
"verifyEraTab"();
```

On the second line it makes complete sense that you'll get an error because you cannot execute a string, the first line is doing the same thing.

**Answer To Original Question**

so you declare `funcs` like this

```
var funcs = (function(){
    var self = {
    verifySearchTab: () => console.log("verify search tab funcs")
  ,
  verifyEraTab: () => console.log("verify era tab funcs")
  }
  return self;
})();
```

so both `verifySearchTab()` and `verifyEraTab()` are both methods of `funcs`

so when you try to run the function on 32 you access it as a member of `funcs` like this

```
funcs[`verify${tab}Tab`]();
```

it gives no error because that method is a member of `funcs`

but when you try to run the function like this

```
`verify${tab}Tab`();
```

it gives you an error because it's not a function, it is however a function inside of `funcs` so you'll have to access it like it's a member of `funcs` because it is like this:

```
funcs[`verify${tab}Tab`]();
```

Comment: what if the code was modified to this instead:

var tabs = ['Search', 'Era'];

function verifySearchTab(){
 console.log("verify search tab");
}

function verifyEraTab(){
  console.log("verify era tab");
}

tabs.forEach(tab => {
 
 console.log(typeof `verify${tab}Tab`);
  `verify${tab}Tab`();
  //let tabName = `verify${tab}Tab`;
  //console.log("tabName = " + tabName);
  
  //funcs[`verify${tab}Tab`]();
});

Comment: if this answered your question please mark it as answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: not quite. I understand that wrapping both the verifySearchTab and verifyEraTab within funcs makes it work-since they are associated with the funcs object. however, what i don't understand is , why doesn't this work?
`verify${tab}Tab`(); I'd expect this statement to work, since function verifySearchTab is now on the window object?

Comment: essentially a in OOP Javascript you can use a function like an object, thus when a function has a property such as a function (as in this case) you have to access it through the containing object or function. it is not a member of window because it was declared inside a function. if you have changed the structure of your code you and are having a different issue you should post a question, this time with complete code from the start.

Comment: I'd edited my original question with the modifications--sorry if it wasn't clear.
let me try it here

`var tabs = ['Search', 'Era'];

function verifySearchTab(){
    console.log("verify search tab");
}

function verifyEraTab(){
  console.log("verify era tab");
}

tabs.forEach(tab => {
  `verify${tab}Tab`();
});`

i see the following error when running the code above:
"TypeError: ((\"verify\" + (intermediate value)) + \"Tab\") is not a function